# TypeScript constructor parameter with modifiers doesn't emit correctly with ts-loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, ts-loader

I was starting to work with a web application built with TypeScript/React/Storybook. I noticed when I write a class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(public a) { }
}

console.log(MyClass);
```

and run the unit tests with jest, or using tsc to emit code, it generates the expected JS code like:

```js
function MyClass(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
```

But when I run it in a Storybook app with development server, it prints out the JS code like:

```js
function MyClass(a) {
  _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);
}
```

I'm thinking if it's related to the TypeScript compiler version picked by ts-loader, but cannot figure it out. I checked the TypeScript version installed to my node_modules folder, and it's v4.1.2, which looks nothing wrong with me.

Also I mentioned Playbook here (and left "playbook" in the tags) only because my app is with it. It might not be directly related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue with recent versions `@babel/preset-typescript` if you are using it. You can change your babel configuration to use `"@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"` **plugin** instead of `@babel/preset-typescript` preset.
More info: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/babel/babel/8752/486541662

If generated by storybook, your babel config probably looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
};
```

Then change it to:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"],
};
```